# Can I use Monitor.Enter/Exit (c# lock) with WPF without fear of reentrancy bugs?

Tags: wpf, multithreading, thread-safety, backgroundworker

If I use Monitor.Enter/Exit (through the c# lock syntax) in a WPF application, can the dispatcher cause re-entrance?

In the sample below, presuming OnTextChanged is called when the text in a textbox changes, could the call to _worker.RunWorkerAsync() be called incorrectly?

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private object _locker = new object();
    private bool _running = false;
    private BackgroundWorker _worker;

    public void SomeClass()
    {
        // initialize worker...
    }

    void _worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        lock (_locker)
            _running = false;
    }

    void _worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // ... do something time consuming ...
    }

    private void OnTextChanged()
    {
        lock(_locker)
        {
            if (!_running)
            {
                _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
                _running = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I believe it's possible, but I've not been able to reproduce this. Does WPF somehow prevent the dispatcher from invoking waiting tasks when waiting on monitor?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you fear.  Both OnTextChanged and RunWorkerCompleted run on the UI thread.  It won't be re-entrant, you don't need the lock either.  Either method can only start running when the UI thread is idle, pumping the message loop.

Comment: I'm afraid of a race condition. Presume the background task is sometimes fast, or is skipped altogether. It's possible that the line in OnTextChanged to set _running = true is run after the call to _running = false. My background task will never run when OnTextChanged is called, b/c _running will forevermore be true. This is especially true if my code can be preempted by the dispatcher (to run some other unrelated task) after the line _worker.RunWorkerAsync() and before _running = true.

Comment: That's not possible.  The `_running` flag is only ever set by code that runs on your main thread.  RunWorkerCompleted can *never* run at the same time as OnTextChanged.  That's the point of using BGW in the first place.  It's pretty well documented in the MSDN library.

Comment: Yes, both run on the the UI thread. Background worker invokes the completed delegate so it's run on the thread it was created on, which of course is the point of BGW. What prevents the background worker's callback from being invoked while the OnTextChanged method would be called, or vice versa? Nothing as far as I'm aware.

Comment: It's pretty simple: when a thread is executing code, it cannot execute other code.  A thread can do only one thing at a time.  If you want to do more than one thing at the same time then you need more than one thread.  BGW helps you avoid shooting your leg off doing so.  The apparent behavior of a UI thread in a GUI program is a carefully crafted way of making it look *to the user* of doing more than one thing at the same time.  That illusion disappears if that "one thing" takes more than 50 milliseconds.  And then you use a BGW.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>While not directly related to your question, you could run into register caching issues if you don't mark `_running` as [`volatile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7%28VS.71%29.aspx).</strike>

Actually this isn't strictly true, as you are not using a double-checked lock. I've left the information related to volatile there anyway, for your reference.